# Ignore the joins without any result in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, coalesce

### Situation

I'm making a SQL server query to filter data from the projects table *(`tblProjecten`)*. This table got a lot of many to many relationships to other tables like region *(`tblProjectenRegio`)*, organisation *(`tblProjectenOrganisatie`)*, etc.

All the parameters I declare are optional. I've found to use `coalesce` to do this. It works fine if I don't use the joins inside my query here you got my query I've use first:

```
declare @themaid int             = 1        ; -- themeID
declare @trefwoord nvarchar(max) = ''       ; -- search query

select distinct p.* 
from tblProjecten p left join tblProjectenThema pt                 on p.projectId = pt.projectId
where pt.themaId        = coalesce(@themaid, pt.themaId)                 and
      p.naam like '%' + @trefwoord + '%'                                    ;
```

Below my results for the different declarations *(see also data below)*:

| @themaid | @trefwoord | results | correct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 166 | OK |
| 1 | airco | 166 | OK |
| null | airco | 166 | OK |
| null |  | 166, 185 , 415 | OK |

This works fine but If I add other conditional parameters like query below. I got totally other results.

```
declare @themaid int             = 1        ;
declare @studiegebiedid int      = null     ;
declare @opleidingdtypeid int    = null     ;
declare @doelgroepid int         = null     ;
declare @organisatorid int       = null     ;
declare @regioid int             = null     ;
declare @trefwoord nvarchar(max) = ''       ;

select distinct p.* 
from tblProjecten p left join tblProjectenThema pt                 on p.projectId = pt.projectId
                    left join tblProjectenStudiegebieden ps        on p.projectId = ps.projectid
                    left join tblProjectenOpleidingsType pot       on p.projectId = pot.projectID
                    left join tblProjectendoelgroep pd             on p.projectId = pd.projectId
                    left join tblProjectenOrganisator po           on p.projectId = po.projectId
                    left join tblProjectenRegio pr                 on p.projectId = pr.projectId
where pt.themaId        = coalesce(@themaid, pt.themaId)                 and
      ps.studiegebiedid = coalesce(@studiegebiedid, ps.studiegebiedid)   and
      pot.opleidingsID  = coalesce(@opleidingdtypeid, pot.opleidingsID)  and
      pd.doelgroepId    = coalesce(@doelgroepid, pd.doelgroepid)         and
      po.organisatorId  = coalesce(@organisatorid, po.organisatorId)     and
      pr.regioId        = coalesce(@regioid, pr.regioId)                 and
      p.naam like '%' + @trefwoord + '%'                                    ;
```

Here are the results *(the other declarations are `null`)*:

| @themaid | @trefwoord | results | correct | must be |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  | NOT OK | 166 |
| 1 | airco |  | NOT OK | 166 |
| null | airco |  | NOT OK | 166 |
| null |  |  | NOT OK | 166, 185, 415 |

This comes because the other tables haven't any data inside it. *(see data below)*

---

### Question

My question is now can I ignore the joins without any result to make the last query working?

I've also tries to use inner and right joins but give the same results.

---

### Data

Here you got some data:

**`tblProjecten`:**

| projectId | naam |
| --- | --- |
| 166 | Attestering AIRCO PROJECT |
| 185 | Autoweb E-LEARNING |
| 415 | Bouw en Hout |

**`tblProjectenThema`:**

| themaId | projectId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 166 |
| 2 | 166 |
| 2 | 415 |
| 3 | 415 |
| 6 | 185 |

**`tblProjectendoelgroep`:**

| doelgroepId | projectId |
| --- | --- |

Comment: Do you select data from the first table only? I see SELECT p.* and no more additional columns. Then, why do you use left joins if no columns are selected from them, just tu multiply the rows of the final resultset?

Comment: @sepupic: Yes I'll have the results from my first table. What you mean with **multiply the rows of the final resultset**? (I'm a junior.)

Comment: I think you want to use `LEFT` joins correctly, i.e. move the conditions from `WHERE` to the respective `ON` conditions.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of values and the expected results you want to see. I'm unclear what you are trying to achieve.  I can tell its something like: "Show me projects that have...." With `LEFT` joins you always get all rows from the `LEFT` side after the join. A `WHERE` clause may then filter out some of those rows.

Comment: @KentChenery I think you are right. I didn't read the question properly. I think they want optional parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been reading and re-reading the original question.  What I have come to is this:

*Return records from tblProjecten where matches exist for parameters that have been supplied (are not null).  Where the parameters are not supplied (or null) then assume all matches for that child table*

Effectively you're making your joins dynamic based on whether a parameter has a supplied value or not.

For that you can use:

```
declare @themaid int             = 1        ;
declare @studiegebiedid int      = null     ;
declare @opleidingdtypeid int    = null     ;
declare @doelgroepid int         = null     ;
declare @organisatorid int       = null     ;
declare @regioid int             = null     ;
declare @trefwoord nvarchar(max) = ''       ;

select p.* 
from tblProjecten p 
where p.naam like '%' + @trefwoord + '%'
and ( 
        @themaid is null
    or exists(select 1 from tblProjectenThema pt where p.projectId = pt.projectId and pt.themaId = @themaid)
)
and (
        @studiegebiedid is null
    or exists(select 1 from tblProjectenStudiegebieden ps where p.projectId = ps.projectid and ps.studiegebiedid = @studiegebiedid
)
and (
        @studiegebiedid is null
    or exists(select 1 from tblProjectenOpleidingsType pot where p.projectId = pot.projectID and ps.studiegebiedid = @studiegebiedid
)
and (
        @opleidingdtypeid is null
    or exists(select 1 from tblProjectendoelgroep pd where p.projectId = pd.projectId and pd.doelgroepId = @doelgroepid
)
and (
        @organisatorid is null
    or exists(select 1 from tblProjectenOrganisator po where p.projectId = po.projectId and po.organisatorId  = @organisatorid
)
and (
        @regioid is null
    or exists(select 1 from tblProjectenRegio pr where p.projectId = pr.projectId and pr.regioId = @regioid
)
```

I have changed things around a little.  Instead of doing joins we're doing an `EXISTS` with a correlated subquery.

Each one evaluates as:

- If @parameter is null return true
- Or... If @parameter is not null then check if there exists a matching record on the child table for that @parameter. If there is, return true

By doing this our joins effectively become optional (depending on whether we have a parameter value or not).

If I have your original intent correct, then an easy assumption is that you might want to use inner joins e.g.:

```
select distinct p.* 
from tblProjecten p
inner join tblProjectenThema pt on p.projectId = pt.projectId
...etc...
where p.naam like '%' + @trefwoord + '%'
and (pt.themaId = coalesce(@themaid))
```

The reason you cannot do this is that tblProjectenThema could be empty and therefore **no** rows can ever be matched.  You would always get an empty result.

### Alternative approach

The query above will start to suffer from performance as more tables need to be considered.  You could use `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` against the query.  Because you want optional, dynamic, parameters this can also be served by using dynamic SQL.

```
declare @themaid int             = 1        ;
declare @studiegebiedid int      = null     ;
declare @opleidingdtypeid int    = null     ;
declare @doelgroepid int         = null     ;
declare @organisatorid int       = null     ;
declare @regioid int             = null     ;
declare @trefwoord nvarchar(max) = ''       ;

select @trefwoord = '%' + @trefwoord + '%';
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

select @sql = '
select p.* 
from tblProjecten p 
where p.naam like @trefwoord
'

if @themaid is not null
select @sql += 'and exists(select 1 from tblProjectenThema pt where p.projectId = pt.projectId and pt.themaId = @themaid)'

if @studiegebiedid is not null 
select @sql += 'and exists(select 1 from tblProjectenStudiegebieden ps where p.projectId = ps.projectid and ps.studiegebiedid = @studiegebiedid)'

if @opleidingdtypeid is not null
select @sql += 'and exists(select 1 from tblProjectendoelgroep pd where p.projectId = pd.projectId and pd.doelgroepId = @doelgroepid)'

if @organisatorid is not null
select @sql += 'and exists(select 1 from tblProjectenOrganisator po where p.projectId = po.projectId and po.organisatorId  = @organisatorid)'

if @regioid is not null
select @sql = +='and exists(select 1 from tblProjectenRegio pr where p.projectId = pr.projectId and pr.regioId = @regioid)'

exec sp_executesql 
    @stmt = @sql
    ,@params = N'@trefwoord nvarchar(max), @themaid int, @studiegebiedid int, @opleidingdtypeid int, @doelgroepid int, @organisatorid int, @regioid int'
    ,@trefwoord = @trefwoord
    ,@themaid = @themaid
    ,@studiegebiedid = @studiegebiedid
    ,@opleidingdtypeid = @opleidingdtypeid
    ,@doelgroepid = @doelgroepid
    ,@organisatorid = @organisatorid
    ,@regioid = @regioid
    ;
```

Comment: Nice. I was editing (with an almost identical query) while you answered.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `LEFT` joins incorrectly. The way the query is now, with a column from each table involved in the `WHERE` clause, the joins  effectively act as `INNER` joins, not `LEFT` joins. As @Kent explained in comment:

When the condition is in the join statement (the `ON` part) the restriction is applied before the join. When it's in the `WHERE`, it's applied after the join occurs (so if you put a condition about the right table, the join effectively becomes an inner join).

Now, I'm not sure about what exactly is wanted.

---

**Case A** (probably not what is wanted). If you want info from the other tables, too, then you should:

- move the conditions from `WHERE` to the respective `ON` conditions
- get rid of the `COALESCE()` functions
- (bonus) get rid of the `DISTINCT`

The query would be something like:

```
select p.*
    -- pt.*, ps.*, ... 
from tblProjecten p 
    left join tblProjectenThema pt
        on  p.projectId = pt.projectId
        and pt.themaId = @themaid 
    left join tblProjectenStudiegebieden ps
        on  p.projectId = ps.projectid
        and ps.studiegebiedid = @studiegebiedid
    left join tblProjectenOpleidingsType pot
        on  p.projectId = pot.projectID
        and pot.opleidingsID = @opleidingdtypeid
    left join tblProjectendoelgroep pd
        on  p.projectId = pd.projectId
        and pd.doelgroepId = @doelgroepid
    left join tblProjectenOrganisator po
        on  p.projectId = po.projectId
        and po.organisatorId = @organisatorid
    left join tblProjectenRegio pr
        on  p.projectId = pr.projectId
        and pr.regioId = @regioid
where  
      p.naam like '%' + @trefwoord + '%'
 ;
```

---

**Case B** (I think this is it). If you want "optional parameters", i.e. when the parameters is null to not restrict the results, then you should:

- convert the joins and `WHERE` conditions to `EXISTS` subqueries
- get rid of the `COALESCE()` functions and use `OR @parameter IS NULL`)
- (bonus) get rid of the `DISTINCT`

The query would be something like:

```
select p.*
from tblProjecten p 
where 
      p.naam like '%' + @trefwoord + '%'
  and ( @themaid is null
      or exists
          ( select * from tblProjectenThema pt
            where p.projectId = pt.projectId
              and pt.themaId = @themaid
          )
      ) 
  and ( @studiegebiedid is null
      or exists
          ( select * from tblProjectenStudiegebieden ps
            where p.projectId = ps.projectId
              and ps.studiegebiedid = @studiegebiedid
          )
      ) 
  -- and ...
 ;
```

Comment: Since the joins are all `LEFT OUTER` joins they become unnecessary as columns are only returned from `tblProjecten`. The parameters have no effect.  I think the OP wants optional parameters, but if provided to then restrict on them.  This changes things vastly.

Comment: @KentChenery thnx. I've added some explanation. Feel free to edit by the way.

Comment: Sorry...I've changed my original comment - although the bits about when restrictions occurs is valid (and helpful).